# How when Button pressed twice the color should change

Tags: objective-c, io, uibutton

I used with NSUserDefaults even though  it is not coming what i requried means
If i click one time on that button it should change the colour to “green” and if i press it again it should change the colour to balck....

Here my Code is.....

```
- (IBAction)subscribeButtonAction:(id)sender {

    if (count == 0) {
        [_subscribeButtonObj setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
        greenStr=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"green"];
        NSUserDefaults *greendefults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [greendefults setValue:greenStr forKey:@"greencolor"];
        [greendefults synchronize];


        ///

        count++;
    }else if(count == 1){
        [_subscribeButtonObj setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
        blackStr=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"black"];
        NSUserDefaults *blackDefaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [blackDefaults setValue:blackStr forKey:@"blackcolor"];
        [blackDefaults synchronize];
        //count = 0;
    }

}
```

in ViewWillAppear i wrote the code like this.....

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

    //count = 0;



    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
         stringForKey:@"greencolor"]) {

        NSLog(@"change the button to green color %@",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
                                                      stringForKey:@"greencolor"]);

    }
    else

    {

        NSLog(@"change the button to blackcolor ");
    }
}
```

Comment: what is your first color? and after become black if i press the button what happen?

Comment: First the button will be in black color,when i click the button it should change to green and if again i press that it should come to black.
when i quit the app and run again the black color button should be visible.Or if i changed the button to green ,after quit nad run the button should be in green

Comment: @iworld if you want to show this color after quitting the app , you should use NSUserDefaults for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you header file write :-

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *myBtn;

- (IBAction)onTapBtn:(id)sender;
```

In your .m file synthesize it  :-

```
@synthesize myBtn;
```

then,

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [myBtn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
    count = 0;
}

- (IBAction)onTapBtn:(id)sender {

    if (count == 0) {
        [myBtn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
        count++;
    }else if(count == 1){
        [myBtn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
        count = 0;
    }
}
```

Thats it,

You can change the color whatever you want and on how many clicks you want, Hope it helps else you can ask me :)

Comment: but when i quit the app the button backgroud color is same as before.I want when i changed the color to green and if i quit from app.Again if i open the app the button should be in green color.

Comment: How to do that.Can you please tell me?

Comment: Just set the required color in viewDidAppear ... did you tried this ?

Comment: @Tech_Intelliswift I think you are using a extra varible to achive this.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a int property to check the state of the button and increment it.

So, here is how my viewController.h looks like:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

enum clickedTimes{
    neverClicked,
    clickedOnce,
    clickedTwice
};

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property int cTimes;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *myButton;

- (IBAction)changeColour:(id)sender;

@end
```

I just create a enum to represent the states, and create the button outlet, also it's action.

My viewController.m:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
//Init the _cTimes property
    _cTimes = neverClicked;
}

- (IBAction)changeColour:(id)sender {
    switch (_cTimes) {
        case neverClicked:
            _myButton.tintColor = [UIColor greenColor];
            _cTimes++;
            break;
        case clickedOnce:
            _myButton.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
            _cTimes++;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps. :)

Comment: If you are looking for data persistence, you should search about how to use NSDefaults. It's pretty simple and fill your needs. Hope you see this comment, I can't comment on another person's posts yet.

Answer (score 0):

hope this will help you

if you make it through .xib file then make an action event like

```
- (IBAction)changeColor:(UIButton *)sender {

    if (sender.isSelected == NO)
    {
        sender.selected =YES;
        sender.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    }
    else
    {
         sender.selected =NO;
        sender.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    }


}
```

and if you making it programmtically

```
UIButton *btn  = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 25, 25)];

[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(changeColor:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

and implement above method.

Answer (score 0):

in its button action

```
- (IBAction)didTapButton:(id)sender {
    UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)sender;
    if (btn.isSelected == NO)
    {
        btn.selected =YES;
        btn.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    }
    else
    {
        btn.selected =NO;
        btn.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    }
}
```

Comment: How can you achieve 3 colors using buttons selected and unselected property ?